# Load data local in file is replacing old data in mariadb columnstore instead of appending new rows

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, mariadb, columnstore

I am loading bulk data using mariadb load data local in file but each time it is replacing new data with the old ones. I need to keep both old and new data in the mariadb columnstore engine data warehouse. Any help regarding this will be highly appreciable.

```
self.log.info("Bulk inserting rows into MySQL destination...")
with closing(mysql_destination.get_conn()) as conn:
   with closing(conn.cursor()) as cursor:
      cursor.execute(
      "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '%s' INTO "
      "TABLE %s LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' (%s)" %
      (tmpfile.name,
      self.mysql_destination_table,
      ", ".join(selected_columns))
      )
   conn.commit()
tmpfile.close()
```

table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `daily_sales_msr_fact`  (
  `id` int(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'autoincrement=1',
  `mtime` timestamp(0) NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `dpid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `route_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `skid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `prid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `group` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `family` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '1990-01-01',
  `sale` double NOT NULL,
  `dprice` double NOT NULL,
  `rprice` double NOT NULL,
  `dcc_price` double NOT NULL,
  `issue` double NOT NULL,
  `return` double NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `memos` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `vmemos` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tlp` double NOT NULL,
  `cnc` double NOT NULL,
  `vp` double NOT NULL,
  `mvp` double NOT NULL,
  `p` double NOT NULL,
  `tcc` double NOT NULL,
  `dcc` double NOT NULL,
  `ecnc` double NOT NULL,
  `gt` double NOT NULL,
  `struc` double NOT NULL,
  `semi_struc` double NOT NULL,
  `streetk` double NOT NULL,
  `mass_hrc` double NOT NULL,
  `pop_hrc` double NOT NULL,
  `prem_hrc` double NOT NULL,
  `kaccounts` double NOT NULL,
  `ogrocery` double NOT NULL,
  `snb_cnc` double NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `pay_n_go` double NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `shop_n_browse` double NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `entertainment` double NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `outlets` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `apps_version` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated` timestamp(0) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `visited` int(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE = Columnstore CHARACTER SET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT = Dynamic;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Comment: that expected check the doc https://mariadb.com/kb/en/load-data-infile/#replace-and-ignore
using replace would add same row but if they share same PK it will replace the row but if you want to add the row in both cases use [{FIELDS | COLUMNS} and do not include the pk column 

and please notice for security reason it not good to use local infile as it could lead the allow of loading file from the client system 
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/load-data-infile/#load-data-local-infile

Comment: i am neither using replace and ignore and also not have declared any column as primary key but still old data are getting replaced by new that is all the old data that are already being in the database are deleted and then new data are being inserted.@justsomeone

Comment: i thought id was pk sorry my bad could you use EXPLAIN EXTENDED daily_sales_msr_fact; and make sure there no unique or pk coloumn

Comment: what does EXPLAIN EXTENDED means and how will i use it in my code?@justsomeone

Comment: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/explain/ login to the mariadb terminal client not your program

Comment: i have used the command and have seen that there is no field defined with primary key in the table.@justsomeone

Comment: sorry not sure the cause but last thing i can think  of that you load the data into another temp table with same structure as yours then use the insert statement while selecting from that new table

Comment: column store is not optimized for operations like SELECT, INSERT, DELETE and UPDATE for single row but your suggestion suggest that. in order for a  better performance for the above operations i am using bulk insertion as mariadb documentation suggests that.@justsomeone

Comment: that why ii said i am not sure the cause of that and tried to give another way around it